# python access memory adress value

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

How can I access the value of an address I found with the cheat engine? The code I wrote is not working.

My code:

```
import ctypes
address = "001788C8"
a = ctypes.cast(address, ctypes.py_object).value
print(a)
```

[image]

Comment: How did you inject Python into Chrome exactly?

Comment: Using an address the way you are attempting is going to read the `python.exe` address space, not `chrome.exe`.  See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52521963/235698) is what you are looking for.